Getting into poetry shell environment and calling jupyter-notebook via a batchfile
Im using poetry shell and I want to create a bactch file that will goto the folder that has the python environment and execute jupyter-notebook command to bring up my jupyter notebook.
The actions I execute as follows:

CD to the folder the with environment
Poetry shell
Jupyter-notebook

I created 2 batch files with the following:
1st batch file Call Poetry.bat:
@ echo off 
cd\
cd C:\Path\PythonScripts
poetry shell

2nd batch file:
@echo off
call "C:\Path\Call Poetry.bat"
call Jupyter-notebook

But when i execute Call Poetry.bat it just gets into the poetry environment command line and waits. When i exit the environment, it then executes the next line which is jupyter-notebook.
How can i get a batch file to get into an environment and then execute commands?
